# How to match user input with excel dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an excel file from which I'm able to read and display data from. After this I want to find a way to get the user to enter an input and compare it with existing cells to find if there is match. How can I achieve this? Sorry for the novice question just a bit new to this

```
import pandas as pd 
df=pd.read_excel("filename.xlsx") 
df
```

Answer (score 0):

They have a built in function for that `DataFrame.duplicated(self, subset=None, keep='first')`.

You can find more info [here](https://thispointer.com/pandas-find-duplicate-rows-in-a-dataframe-based-on-all-or-selected-columns-using-dataframe-duplicated-in-python/) but basically:

```py
duplicateRowsDF = dfObj[dfObj.duplicated()]

print("Duplicate Rows except first occurrence based on all columns are :")
print(duplicateRowsDF)
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I'll give that a run and see how it goes!